# When should we split the dataset into test and train?

Tags: split, dataset

I am new to Machine Learning and I am given a dataset, so I want to know the exact steps in sequence to process a dataset before we dive into modelling.
From my understanding,
We first need to clean the data (remove duplicates, handle null,...)
visualise the data
then feature selection -(make new features)

so are we supposed to split the data after feature selection and then start with modelling?
I am really confused!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote some of them there, the lifecycle of Machine Learning is like below in my point;

1. Collecting the data
2. Study on the collected data, which features are categorical which
   features are numerical etc. (learn the data types)
3. Begin to data manipulation / cleaning doing such as removing
   duplicates, outliers, highly correlated things (i.e. if there are
   two features male and female remove one of them because if you are
   not male, you are 100% female.)
4. Visualize your data to observe outliers, correlations etc.
5. If you have categorical datas you need convert them to numerical
6. Separate the dependent and independent features.
7. Feature selection, choose some of most important features
8. Decide what to do based on your how many samples do you have.
9. If it is not too much, it means every samples/records are important for you and consider cross validation
10. After splitting the data, check the datas again. If your features have different units and there are big differences between them, you should consider to do "Normalization or Standardization" methods to use same units/scales
11. Everything has been done. Decide which evaluation metrics you want to choose. Define your goals on the projects. What do you want?
12. Then choose the models. After fitting and predicting process, check your evaluation models, scores. Which one has the highest score?  (While doing this, I suggest you to count the time. Time is really important factor. You should consider it too.)

> One accurate measurement is worth more than a thousand expert opinions

You can check one of my project in github here => https://github.com/erolerdogan/Property-Maintenance-Fines

I hope these steps help you to understand more. These are my point. If someone edits, adds or shows my error, I would be greatly happy. Thanks